# Get all of the evaluated instance variables of an instance without the representation of the object itself

Tags: java

I have a class representing some kind of documents, defined by certain variables. Some of these variables are shared between all the document types, while some others are specific of a particular document type, and also some variables needs to be always evaluated, but some others don't (therefore, given a specific instance of a generic document, I never know in advance which variables are evaluated and which are not, except for the mandatory ones).

The final goal is to ah HashMap representing a document, which has to contain ONLY the evaluated attributes of the instance I'm trying to represent (both "general" and specific). To do so, I tried the method shown, but it gives me only the specific variables and it always gives me something I don't want, which seems to be a representation of the instance itself

My question is: is there a way to improve that method in a way that given an object which will always be an instance of a MyDocument subclass, gives me back the HashMap I need?

Here's the MyDocument class

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import it.smi.json.JSONArray;
import it.smi.json.JSONObject;

public class MyDocument {

    String documentClass;               // mandatory
    String name;                        // mandatory
    String notes;                       // NOT mandatory
    
    public class Contract extends MyDocument {

        String providerCode;                // mandatory
        String providerName;                // mandatory
        long activationDate;                // mandatory
        long expirationDate;                // mandatory
        String expirationNotifyUser;        // NOT mandatory
        String expirationNotifyUserType;    // NOT mandatory
        
        Contract (String name, String notes, long activationDate, long expirationDate) {
            
            this.documentClass = "contract";    // constant
            this.name = name;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.providerCode = null;
            this.providerName = null;
            this.activationDate = activationDate;
            this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
            this.expirationNotifyUser = null;
            this.expirationNotifyUserType = null;
            
        } // init
        
    }
    
    public class Summary extends MyDocument {

        String origin;                      // mandatory
        String providerCode;                // NOT mandatory
        String providerName;                // NOT mandatory

        Summary (String name, String notes) {
            
            this.documentClass = "summary";
            this.origin = "area";           // constant
            this.name = name;
            this.notes = notes;
            this.providerCode = null;
            this.providerName = null;
            
        } // init
        
    }

    
    public HashMap<String, Object> getProperties () throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> toReturn = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for(Field f : fields) if (f.get(this) != null) toReturn.put(f.getName(), f.get(this)); 
            // I tried to add 
            //!f.getName().contains("this$") && 
            // to the if, which works on my machine, but I don't really like it because 
            // I'm not sure it will work the same way once deployed on server
        return toReturn;
    } // getProperties
    
}
```

and the result

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        
    Summary summ = new MyDocument().new Summary("SumName", "SumNotes");
    Contract cont = new MyDocument().new Contract("ContName", "ContNotes", 12345, 67890);
        
        System.out.println("### Summary:\n" + summ.getProperties());
        System.out.println("### Contract:\n" + cont.getProperties());
        
        /*
         * gives me back:
         * 
            ### Summary:
            {origin=area, this$0=myName.test.generic.MyDocument@6d06d69c}
            ### Contract:
            {this$0=myName.test.generic.MyDocument@4e25154f, activationDate=12345, expirationDate=67890}
        
        * while I need:
        * 
            ### Summary:
            {documentClass=summary, name=SumName, notes=SumNotes, origin=area}
            ### Contract:
            {documentClass=contract, name=ContName, notes=ContNotes, activationDate=12345, expirationDate=67890}
         */
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1. `getDeclaredFields()` returns the `Field` objects for only the fields declared by the target class.  The fields declared in inherited classes and interfaces are not included in the result.  If you want those you need to (recursively) scan the classes superclass (`getSuperclass()`) and its interfaces (`getInterfaces()`).  Read the javadocs for those methods carefully ... because there is a catch.
2. The field called `this$0` is a *synthetic* field.  You can tell if a field is synthetic by calling `isSynthetic()` on the `Field` object.  A synthetic field's name is platform dependent *in theory*, but not in practice (AFAIK).

In this case, `Contract` and `Summary` have been declared as innerclasses of `MyDocument`.  The "this$0" synthetic field is used when (say) an instance method of `Contract` needs to refer to the instance of `MyDocument` that (um) contains it.  If you don't need to be able to do that, you could declare `Contract` and `Summary` as nested classes instead; i.e. add the `static` keyword before the respective `class` keywords.

Comment: Thanks for the point 2, that works fine! 
About the point 1, adding the static modifier just removed the need for the new Document(), but that's it. I think I'll just create a specific getProperties() for every subclass where i build manually the map.

Comment: I don't think you understood what I wrote.  Specifically, my point 1 is to visit all of the superclasses and interfaces to find all of the declared fields.  Adding `static` is an alternative way to get rid of the synthetic field.  No way would or could it deal with the missing fields.  I strongly recommend that you read / reread the javadocs for `getDeclaredFields` ... and note well the difference in meaning between declared fields and inherited fields.